# В чем причина получения default значения при Intent?

Tags: java, android-intent

Пытаюсь передать int значение из одного класса в другой, но значение не передается и присваивается default значение.

Класс, с которого отправляем int значение

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleBottomSheetDialog.class);
myIntent.putExtra("level", level);
```

Класс, который должен получить int значение

```
int level = getActivity().getIntent().getIntExtra("level", 0)
```

В чем ошибка может быть?

Comment: `getActivity` указывает на то, что вы пытаетесь получить значение во фрагменте, к фрагменту не бывает интента, фрагмент вызывает только

Comment: @McDaggen без `getActivity` получается ошибка с `getIntent()` (Cannot resolve method 'getIntent()'. `getActivity` добавила по результатам изучения форумов.

Comment: Если было правильно замечано в комментариях выше и это действительно Fragment, то я предлагаю пользоваться Bundle. Как-то вот так https://mobikul.com/pass-data-activity-fragment-android/